# Executing several mongoose queries: how to use promises instead?

Tags: asynchronous, coffeescript, express, mongoose, promise

I have the following code and I would like to avoid nested callbacks:

```
app.get '/performers', (req, res) ->
    conductor = require('models/conductor').init().model
    soloist = require('models/soloist').init().model
    orchestra = require('models/orchestra').init().model
    chamber = require('models/chamber').init().model
    performers = {}
    conductor.find {}, (err, result) ->
        performers.conductor = result
        soloist.find {}, (err, result) ->
            performers.soloist = result
            orchestra.find {}, (err, result) ->
                performers.orchestra = result
                chamber.find {}, (err, result) ->
                    performers.chamber = result
                    res.json performers
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find the [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async) library to be a cleaner solution than promises for this sort of thing.  For this specific case, [`async.parallel`](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel) would work well.

I'm not overly familiar with coffeescript, but it would look something like this:

```
performers = {}
async.parallel [
    (callback) ->
        conductor.find {}, (err, result) ->
            performers.conductor = result
            callback err
    (callback) ->
        soloist.find {}, (err, result) ->
            performers.soloist = result
            callback err
    (callback) ->
        orchestra.find {}, (err, result) ->
            performers.orchestra = result
            callback err
    (callback) ->
        chamber.find {}, (err, result) ->
            performers.chamber = result
            callback err
    ], (err) ->
        res.json performers
```

Comment: Can you explain the first return statement in each function?

Comment: I've updated the example to use an object instead of an array. This way the parallel execution builds your object for you. https://gist.github.com/kim3er/6594588

Answer (score 1):

You can also organize your code like this:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
    var _self = {};

    var foundItems = function(err, items){
      _self.items = items;
      res.render('index', { user: _self.user, items: _self.items, lists: _self.lists });
    };

    var foundLists = function(err, lists){
      _self.lists = lists;
      Items.find().exec(foundItems);
    };

    var foundUser = function(err, user){
      _self.user = user;
      List.find().exec(foundLists);
    };

    User.findById(user).exec(foundUser);
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure if we are talking about the same situation here.

Comment: each find callback takes a function, it is a way to flatten out the nesting that occurs. I think async lib might be more readable though..