# Handling data with get request in node with mongodb database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Noob question.. How I can synchronize the mongoose query with the JSON response? The following code return empty values because the query ends later. Which is the way to handle it?

```
router.route('/admin')
    .get(function (req, res ) {
        var country = [];
        var element = [];
        Country.find({}, function (err, data) {
            country = data; 
        });
        Items.find({}, function (err, data) {    
            element = data;         
        }); 
        res.json({
            countries: country,
            elements: element
        });         
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

country.find and Items.find are asynchronously executed - and run at the same time. 
You need to nest them them in the callback functions to honor the asynchronous execution mode - that way you make sure they are executed synchronously. So your code needs to look like this:

```
Country.find({}, function (err, data) {
        country = data; 
        Items.find({}, function (err, data) {    
            element = data;        
            res.json({
              countries: country,
              elements: element
            });   
        }); 
    });
```

a more advanced and probably better way would be using a promise library- which would mean they are still executed asynchronously, but the complete result is only returned once all results of all functions are available  - which is explained here:

[Executing several mongoose queries: how to use promises instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13219266/executing-several-mongoose-queries-how-to-use-promises-instead)

Comment: Thanks. Your solutions works, but I'm looking for a nice way to handle this scenario and the link reference is still confusing for me.

Comment: the "nicest" way in terms of what is the state of things in asynchronous programming (and in case you haven't noticed - welcome to the wild and wonderous world of asynchronous programming - it was hard for me to understand as well in the first place, especially if you come out of "classic" synchronous languages like Java ;)  - is using a Promise - which is a design pattern that allow execution of multiple asynchronous processes - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises

Comment: I did already that asynchronous calls with jQuery, defining the async parameter in the ajax call. Width node I was expecting  a similar way to handle it. I will take a look at the promise pattern with more calm.